# How to use modbus 16 function in ScadaLTS

Tags: scada, scadalts

I don't make sure, but I think the ScadaLTS no have the modbus 16 function. I need write in 9 registers simultaneously, but the data type that ScadaLTS give does not satisfy my need. I did try to use the type data "fixed length string" but I can't represent the code 0 in ASCII, if I could, it would work.

Finally, I hope to find help and thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I think we do not support this but please give me more details. So that I could simulate such a situation in ScadaLTS using local mod_RSsim.

Answer (score 0):

Modbus function 16 is writing multiple holding register address at once, we cannot write it one by one, and must use fc 16 code. But there is no option to write to multiple address at modbus datapoint. I need this feature also,